# Как проверить запись в базе данных на существование?

Tags: php

Есть форма регистрации, которая заносит имя пользователя и пароль в базу данных.

```
<?php
$login = $_POST['username'];
$pass = $_POST['password'];
$servername = "localhost";
$database = "test";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, 
$username, $password, $database);
if (!$conn) {
die("Connection failed: " . 
mysqli_connect_error());
}

echo "Успешное подключение к базе данных ";

$sql = "INSERT INTO Click (username, 
password) VALUES ('$login', '$pass')";
if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
echo "Ошибка: " . $sql . "
" . mysqli_error($conn);
}
mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

Как проверить, существует ли такой username в базе, и если существует то выдать ошибку, а если не существует то занести его в базу?

Comment: Рекомендую научиться обращаться за помощью в первую очередь в поисковую систему , данный вопрос максимально популярен и на него присутствует множество ответов. [Первая же ссылка сюда же на stackoverflow](https://www.google.com.ua/search?q=%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C%20%D1%81%D1%83%D1%89%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D1%83%D0%B5%D1%82%20%D0%BB%D0%B8%20%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8C%20%D0%B2%20%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B5&oq=%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C%20%D1%81%D1%83%D1%89%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D1%83%D0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Начнем с того, что в этом коде куча проблем, одна из которых SQL-инъекция. В эту форму злюка может отправить волшебные символы и сделать с вашей базой всё, что захочет. Пофиксить несложно, на все данные, которые отправляются к базе, использовать функцию `mysql_escape_string` или в вашем случае `mysql_real_escape_string($conn, VAR)`

Чтобы проверить запись в базе, нужно использовать вот такой запрос:
`SELECT * FROM Click WHERE username = '".$login."' AND pass = '".$pass."'`

```
<?php
    $servername = "localhost";
    $database = "test";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "";
    if (!$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $database)) die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
    else echo "Успешное подключение к базе данных ";

    $login = mysql_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['username']);
    $pass = mysql_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['password']);

    $check = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM Click WHERE username = '".$login."' AND pass = '".$pass."'"));
    if($check != null) echo "Запись уже существует";
    else {
        $sql = "INSERT INTO Click (username, password) VALUES ('".$login."', '".$pass."')";

        if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
            echo "New record created successfully";
        } else {
            echo "Ошибка: ".$sql.mysqli_error($conn);
        }
    }
?>
```

Не помешало бы Вам почитать официальную документацию и синтаксис MySQL

Comment: Было пару ошибок в вашем коде. Например у меня везде используется mysqli, а у вас mysql. И так же малозаметная, но ошибка была с именем в строке 11, у вас указано "pass", а нужно было "password". И последние это то что даже если запись была найдена, то она всё равно добавляется в таблицу, но оператор "exit;" после объявления об уже существующей записи отлично помог. После исправления этих маленьких недочётов всё отлично заработало, спасибо!

Comment: я ответил конкретно на ваш вопрос, а код скинул как пример. то, что вы нашли ошибки, вы большой молодец, я писал на одном дыхании и только как образец.
а вот насчет если запись существует, она никак не добавится в базу, потому что если запись есть, у неё условие вывести текст, ниже неё ничего нет, обратите внимание на `else`

Comment: Согласен с teamspam, просто почитайте что такое экранизирование элементов типа кавычек в запросах (Если уж вам нужен драйвер mysqli - https://www.php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.real-escape-string.php), это сможет защитить вас от SQL-инъекции. (Но! Не во всех случаях, если хотите защититься полностью - изучите prepared запросы).

Comment: А по поводу проверки существования записи в таблице - пример абсолютно верен.